# Use same serializer class but with different action in a view in Django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, primary-key, django-serializer

I have a modelset view in which different customs functions are defined based on the requirement. I have to write another get function in which I want to use the same serializer class. But the field which I have defined in the serializer class in pkfield but for the get function, I want it as a stringfield rather than pk field. How to achieve that??

Also, I have defined depth=1, which is also not working.

```
class Class(TimeStampAbstractModel):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(
                                Teacher,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True,
                                related_name="online_class",
    )
    subject = models.ForeignKey(
                                Subject,
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                null= True,
                                related_name= "online_class",
    )
    students_in_class = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name="online_class")
```

My view:

```
class ClassView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Class.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClassSerializer
    serializer_action_classes = {
        'add_remove_students': AddStudentstoClassSerializer,
        'get_all_students_of_a_class': AddStudentstoClassSerializer,
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):

        """
            returns a serializer class based on the action
            that has been defined.
        """
        try:
            return self.serializer_action_classes[self.action]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            return super(ClassView, self).get_serializer_class()
        
       def add_remove_students(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       """ 
       serializer class used is AddStudentstoClassSerializer
       """
       def get_all_students_of_a_class(self,request,pk=None):
       """
       for this I function too, I want to use the same AddStudentstoClassSerializer class but 
       there is a problem. The field students_in_class is already defined as pkfield, whereas I
       want to use it as a stringfields in the response of this function
       """"
```

My serializer:

```
class AddStudentstoClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students_in_class = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Student.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = ["students_in_class"]
        depth = 1

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        slug = self.context["slug"]
        stu = validated_data.pop("students_in_class")
        /................other codes....../
        return instance
```

Here we can see the student_in_class is defined as pkfield which is ok when using the update api, but when I want to use the get api and call `get_all_students_of_a_class` I want the field to be stringfield or some other field. How to do that? Also `depth= 1` is also not working.

**Update:**

Treid the following but still not working:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    rep = super().to_representation(instance)
    # rep["students_in_class"] = instance.students_in_class
    rep['students_in_class'] = StudentSerializer(instance.students_in_class).data
    return rep

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['user', 'college_name', 'address']
```

what i got in the response is

```
{
    "students_in_class": {}
}
```

it is empty dict. what should be done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override you `to_representation` method like this.

```
class AddStudentstoClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students_in_class = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Student.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = ["students_in_class"]
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = {
            "students_in_class": # Write your logic here
        }
        return data

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        slug = self.context["slug"]
        stu = validated_data.pop("students_in_class")
        /................other codes....../
        return instance
```

Comment: hello hassan, can you please check my updated code. its not working...

Comment: Change your line to `StudentSerializer(instance.students_in_class.all(), many=True).data`

Comment: yes, that worked perfectly, but instead of showing all the fields, can i show specific fields only of students??

Comment: You can write new seializer for that or like this `instance.students_in_class.all().values('field1', 'field2')`. You will not serializer for this if you use 2nd method.